# How to delete a record by mongo obiect id. I have using new mongoId and new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId

Tags: mongodb

How can I delete a record by Mongo ObiectId?

I have passed this:`{"$oid":"5e4a3d94a3968198e157c158"}` in delete query using php.

I used like this - `new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId({"$oid":"5e4a3d94a3968198e157c158"})`

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this with php 
You can do this like this

```
[ "_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID("5e4a3d94a3968198e157c158") ]
```

If you need to do this from mongoshel

```
db.collectionName.remove({"_id" : ObjectId("5e4a3d94a3968198e157c158")},{justOne: true})
```

If you have any question feel free to ask

Comment: i am using like this : 
[ "_id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID({"$oid":"5e4a3d94a3968198e157c158"}) ]

Comment: try without $oid just like I suggested in answer.